# Why is my nested table column width incorrect in IE but not Chrome?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-tables

I've created [this fiddle to experiment aligning columns between tables and their contained sub-tables.](https://jsfiddle.net/Exaxis/wx92stvs/)

To achieve this, I utilize colgroups and specify column widths in my CSS like so:

```
  <colgroup>
    <col class="orderNumColumnWidth"/>
    <col class="itemNumColumnWidth"/>
    <col class="itemNameColumnWidth"/>
    <col class="itemDescColumnWidth"/>
  </colgroup>
```

In Chrome, the column widths are correctly calculated and match up nicely:

[image]

However, in IE 11, the first column in my sub-table is mis-aligned by a few pixels:

[image]

The mis-alignment is small, but I can't figure out why it is there, or why the Item # column is mis-aligned but the Name column is not.

What confuses me further is that, if I investigate with the f12 menu in IE, it actually says that the Item# column header is *wider* than the contents, which doesn't appear to be the case by looking at it.

Does anyone have an idea as to what causes this, and how I can fix it?

Comment: in my IE11 there is no misalignmemt  http://i.stack.imgur.com/THX2P.jpg

Comment: That's very interesting. Do you know what your version is? mine is 11.0.9600.18230 with Update Version 11.0.29

Comment: here you go http://i.stack.imgur.com/kH3ub.jpg :)

Comment: Thanks for the info! It looks like we have the exact same version, with only the language being different.Strange!

Comment: okay, maybe then it has to do with screen resolution or hardware setting . sorry, can't help much more here :)

Comment: For completeness, here is my screenshot from Mozilla. http://i.stack.imgur.com/u7Hgy.jpg It looks like it's to do with the font used. If I add `body {font-family:Times New Roman}` to the css, everything is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Mr Lister! I changed my font the same way you have in IE 11, but that hasn't changed anything for me. But it obviously had a big impact for you, which is important to note.